# Detect ASTM protocol end of transmission

Tags: java, sockets, hl7

I am  working on implementing a software for connecting to analyzer and receive lab data.

I faced a problem on how to detect the end of transmission between the analyzer and my software.

The program receive the data correctly but I faced a problem on how to detect the end of transmission when the analyzer finish sending data so I can send it to other server.
The communication specification for ASTM E1394-97, E1381-02/95 section 2.2.3 mention that; the ETX character is the indication for the end of text and EOT character is the indicator of the end of transmission.

In my program I check the received byte to check if the character is ETX or EOT so I can close the socket and use the data, also I checked the received if it equal -1 EOF.

For unknown reason the analyzer did not send any of these characters- ETX and EOT.

**Is there any method to detect that the analyzer end the transmission of data?**

Following is a simple code for accepting connection from the analyzer.

```
package ServerClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class SimpleServer {

    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static Socket connection;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        server = new ServerSocket(5006);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(" start... ");
            connection = server.accept();
            System.out.println("wait for connection");
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            int i = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            do // process messages sent from client
            {
                try // read message and display it
                {
                    //System.out.println("wait for message");
                    i = inFromServer.read();

                    System.out.println((char) i + " " + i);
                    //System.out.print(" *" + i + " " + (char) i + "* ");
                    sb.append((char) i);
                    //byte ACK = 0x06;
                    //outToServer.writeByte(ACK);
                    //outToServer.flush();

                    /*
                    outToServer.write(0);
                    i = inFromServer.read();
                    System.out.println(i);*/
                } // end try
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    connection.close();

                    break;
                } // end catch

            } while (true && i != -1);
            System.out.println("--------------\n" + sb.toString() + "\n--------------");
            connection.close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the analyzer use [Minimal Lower Layer Protocol](http://www.hl7.org/documentcenter/public_temp_F7868E08-1C23-BA17-0CA41FF533166B7D/wg/inm/mllp_transport_specification.PDF)?

Comment: yes it use LLP protocol

Comment: then end of transmission should be `<EB><CR>` followed by socket closed (-1)

Comment: in my case i did not receive -1, is there any reason for that?

Comment: if the socket is still open then the transmission was not terminated. Analyzer may still send some more data after a while. Why do you need the _transmission terminated_ signal after all?

Comment: I need the termination signal because it indicates that the transmitter finishes data transmission, after that i can close the connection and process the received data

Answer (score 1):

you are  using infinite *While Loop* so you will not be able to break loop after **ETX** character received from analyzer.For **ASTM communication** with analyzer you have to break loop after **ETX** character received .below code completely  running perfect .

Kindly take a look on below Link and you will get alot of help about ASTM

**Link :** [ASTM Communication Detail and Its fully Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238341/how-to-write-and-send-an-astm-frame-to-medical-equipment-in-java/49257294#49257294)

```
   while (true) {
   while((clientIntMessag=inFromClient.read())!=ASCIIValues.ETX) {
          currentMsg += "" + (char) clientIntMessage;
                if (clientIntMessage == ASCIIValues.ENQ) {
                    outToClient.writeBytes("" + ASCIIValues.ACK);
                } 
                if (clientIntMessage == ASCIIValues.LF) {
                    outToClient.writeBytes("" + ASCIIValues.ACK);
                }
                if (clientIntMessage == ASCIIValues.NAK) {
                    outToClient.writeBytes("" + ASCIIValues.EOT);
                }
            }

             System.out.println(currentMsg);

            currentMsg = "";


        }
```

If you have still any confusion kindly let me know..