# How to write and send an ASTM frame to medical equipment

Tags: java, string, checksum, astm

I am currently working on the ASTM protocol to send orders tests request to medical instrument. But I cannot send a message to the equipment correctly. To be more explicit, I want for example to send these frames:

```
        String h1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6 = "";
        h1 = "H|@^\\|ODM-IdfDGIWA-36|||GeneXpert PC^GeneXpert^4.8|||||LIS||P|1394-97|20070521100245";
        s2 = "P|1";
        s3 = "O|1|SID-818||^^^TestId-12|S|20070812140500|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
        s4 = "O|2|SID-818||^^^TestId-14|S|20070812140600|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
        s5 = "O|3|SID-818||^^^TestId-16|S|20070812140700|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
        s6 = "L|1|F";
```

and here is how I am doing now:

```
    writeMeBytes(outToServer, h1.getBytes());
    writeMeBytes(outToServer, s2.getBytes());
    writeMeBytes(outToServer, s3.getBytes());
    writeMeBytes(outToServer, s4.getBytes());
    writeMeBytes(outToServer, s5.getBytes());
    writeMeBytes(outToServer, s6.getBytes());


public static void writeMeBytes(DataOutputStream dos, byte [] b){
    if (b.length >0){
        int j = 0;
        while (j <= b.length-1) {
            try {
                dos.write(b[j++]);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SimpleServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I turn it into byte and then send byte after byte.

Except that I do not see any change on the receiver side.

**Update according to @Muhammad Answer**

This is what I did to send order to GeneXpert DX System

```
public class SimpleServer {

private static ServerSocket server;
private static Socket connection;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    server = new ServerSocket(12221);
    boolean stopped = false;

    System.out.println(" start... ");
    connection = server.accept();
    System.out.println("wait for connection");
    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    String currentMsg = "";
    int clientIntMessage;

    String h1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6 = "";
    h1 = "1H|@^\\|ODM-IdfDGIWA-36|||GeneXpert PC^GeneXpert^4.8|||||LIS||P|1394-97|20070521100245" + ProtocolASCII.LF
            + "P|1" + ProtocolASCII.LF
            + "O|1|SID-818||^^^TestId-12|S|20070812140500|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q" + ProtocolASCII.LF
            + "L|1|F" + ProtocolASCII.LF;
    s2 = "P|1";
    s3 = "O|1|SID-818||^^^TestId-12|S|20070812140500|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
    //s4 = "O|2|SID-818||^^^TestId-14|S|20070812140600|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
    //s5 = "O|3|SID-818||^^^TestId-16|S|20070812140700|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
    s6 = "L|1|F";

    String retmsg = h1;
    //logException("OrderMessae   :" + retmsg);
    retmsg = ProtocolASCII.STX + retmsg + ProtocolASCII.CR + ProtocolASCII.ETX + ProtocolMessage.getCheckSum(retmsg) + ProtocolASCII.CR + ProtocolASCII.LF;

    clientIntMessage = inFromClient.read();
    //while (clientIntMessage != ProtocolASCII.EOT) {
    while (true) {
        currentMsg += String.valueOf(Character.toChars(clientIntMessage));
        if (clientIntMessage == ProtocolASCII.ENQ) {
            outToClient.writeBytes("" + ProtocolASCII.ACK);
            System.out.println(" <--- LIS [ACK] on DX [ENQ]");
        } else if (clientIntMessage == ProtocolASCII.ACK) {
            System.out.println(" ---> DX [ACK]");
            // Send your order message here
            outToClient.writeBytes(retmsg);
        } else if (clientIntMessage == ProtocolASCII.CR) {
            System.out.println(currentMsg);
            outToClient.writeBytes("" + ProtocolASCII.ACK);
        } else if (clientIntMessage == ProtocolASCII.NAK) {
            System.out.println(" ---> DX sent [NAK] ");
            System.out.println(" --- LIS now wait 10 sec... ");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            outToClient.writeBytes("" + ProtocolASCII.ENQ);
            System.out.println(" <--- LIS [ENQ] ");
        } else if (clientIntMessage == ProtocolASCII.EOT) {
            System.out.println(" ---> DX END OF TRANSMISSION");
            outToClient.writeBytes("" + ProtocolASCII.ENQ);
            System.out.println(" <--- LIS [ENQ] ");
        }

        if (stopped) {
            break;
        }
        clientIntMessage = inFromClient.read();
    }
    connection.close();
    stopped = true;
}}
```

And this is the result I get from the console:

```
start... 
wait for connection
 <--- LIS [ACK] on DX [ENQ]
1H|@^\|ODM-rQTcjIWA-66||GeneXpert PC^GeneXpert^4.8|||||LIS||P|1394-97|20180314003724
Q|1|ALL||||||||||O@N
L|1|N
B5
 ---> DX [EOT] 
 <--- LIS [ENQ] 
 ---> DX [ACK]
 ---> DX sent [NAK] 
 --- LIS now wait 10 sec...
```

DX is the machine software and LIS is the host. 
Whenever I try to send the ENQ, the machine answers me with NAK.

**UPDATE 2**
It seem to be working. But now windows events shows me an error about why my records orders don't appear in the GeneXpert DX host record list. The header record have been sent first.

[image: Windows event logs after following @Muhammad *UPDATE 2**]

[image: GeneXpert DX STATUS]

Comment: Are you sure you should be using a `DataOutputStream`? And using `String.getBytes()` without explicitly specifying a character set is an accident waiting to happen. Also please clarify how it doesn't work. You're not providing us a lot to go on.

Comment: I use `DataOutputStream` because the connexion is done by the socket, and i have to write bytes to communicate with the receiver. As you can see in top, the string is firstly initialized before `getBytes()`. 

To be more explicit, I want to order the client to start a test by sending him the information on the patient from the frame above. But the concern is that after typing orders that are lower, I do not see the result at the client.

Do you know how to translate ASTM request in JAVA?

I take inspiration on this http://www.med-kim.com.tr/images/kataloglar/5d7cc11c-e.pdf

Comment: A `DataOutputStream` is for writing a very specific data format, you likely need a plain `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before answering, lets discuss machine mechanism for Bidirectional.

```
String h1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6 = "";
    h1 = "H|@^\\|ODM-IdfDGIWA-36|||GeneXpert PC^GeneXpert^4.8|||||LIS||P|1394-97|20070521100245";
    s2 = "P|1";
    s3 = "O|1|SID-818||^^^TestId-12|S|20070812140500|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
    s4 = "O|2|SID-818||^^^TestId-14|S|20070812140600|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
    s5 = "O|3|SID-818||^^^TestId-16|S|20070812140700|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
    s6 = "L|1|F";
```

**First**, viewing above String message, there isn't any tag numbering as every machine I have done so far requires **Tag number**. For example:

```
1H|\^&|||CS-2500^00-08^22029^^^CP^BV981798||||||||E1394-97
2P|1|||00000152556|^JOHN^ABC||19440601|M|||||^Dr.Shaukat Khanum Hospital|||||||||^^^EAST
3O|1|000038^01^0012586236^B||^^^051^^100.00¥^^^044^^100.00|R|201803081225236|||||N
4L|1|N
```

So, you must have **NUMBERING** for each tag.

**Second**, Machine sends following query at first time:

```
1H|\^&|||CS-2500^^22029^^^CP^BV981798||||||||E1394-9711
2Q|1|000038^01^   0012365845B||^^^040^PT-INN\^^^050^APTT-FS|0|201803081227007F
3L|1|NF9
```

In, Query(2Q) Tag, `000038` rack id, `01` rack sequence number, `001H18074618` sample id (read from Barcode), further information can be verified from host or LIS manual provided by machine vendor.

**Third**, When we receive this message, we will make message for machine that I have described above (writing again below) with additional **checksum** information. Again, this checksum can be found in host or LIS manual of machine.

```
1H|\^&|||CS-2500^00-08^22029^^^CP^BV981798||||||||E1394-97
2P|1|||00000152556|^JOHN^ABC||19440601|M|||||^Dr.Shaukat Khanum Hospital|||||||||^^^EAST
3O|1|000038^01^12345678^B||^^^051^^100.00¥^^^044^^100.00|R|201803081225236|||||N
4L|1|N
```

Example of Checksum calculation. Note that it may vary from machine to machine.

```
  public static String getCheckSum(String msg) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
        sum += msg.charAt(i);
    }
    sum += 16; //adding CR and ETX AND ETB
    sum = sum % 256;
    String checksum = Integer.toHexString(sum).toUpperCase();
    if (checksum.length() == 1) {
        checksum = "0" + checksum;
    }
    //System.out.println("\n Check Sum is ="+checksum);
    return checksum;
}
```

And here is our complete message that will be sent to machine:

```
String retmsg = "3O|1|" + rackId + "^" + positionNumber + "^" + sampleId + "^B||" + testIds + "|" + priority + "|" + sysDate + "|||||" + orderType + "";
    logException("OrderMessae   :" + retmsg);
    retmsg = ProtocolASCII.STX + retmsg + ProtocolASCII.CR + ProtocolASCII.ETX + ProtocolMessage.getCheckSum(retmsg) + ProtocolASCII.CR + ProtocolASCII.LF;
```

**Last but not least**, I don't know what is the machine as I don't have manual but I sense that you don't need to send every message one by one. You can send all at once.

here is the code snippet of sending and receiving message to and from machine.

```
while (clientIntMessage != ProtocolASCII.EOT) {
                    clientIntMessage = inFromClient.read();
                    currentMsg += String.valueOf(Character.toChars(clientIntMessage));
                    // System.out.println(currentMsg);
                    if (clientIntMessage == ProtocolASCII.ENQ) {
                        outToClient.writeBytes("" + ProtocolASCII.ACK);
                        System.out.println("[ACK] on Analyzer [ENQ]");
                    } else if (clientIntMessage == ProtocolASCII.ACK) {                        
                        System.out.println("Analyzer [ACK]");
                        // Send your order message here
                         outToClient.writeBytes(retmsg);
                        }
                    } else if (clientIntMessage == ProtocolASCII.LF) {
                        outToClient.writeBytes("" + ProtocolASCII.ACK);
                    } else if (clientIntMessage == ProtocolASCII.NAK) {
                        System.out.println(" Analyzer sent [NAK] ");
                    }

                }
```

Where **ProtocolASCII.ACK** is `'\006'`, **ProtocolASCII.ENQ** is `'\005'` and **ProtocolASCII.EOT** is `'\004'`.

The code is pretty much self explanatory and I am using it in production.

Can you tell us which machine you are interfacing? It may help you if I have already integrated.

Thanks . If further assistance is required, let me know.

For your reference:

```
public class ProtocolASCII {

  public static char STX = '\002';
  public static char ETX = '\003';
  public static char ETB = '\027';
  public static char EOT = '\004';
  public static char ENQ = '\005';
  public static char ACK = '\006';
  public static char NAK = '\025';
  public static char CR = '\r';
  public static char LF = '\n';
  public static char MOR = '>';
  public static char FS = '\034';
  public static char GS = '\035';
  public static char RS = '\036';
  public static char SFS = '\027';
  public static char VT = 0x0B; //END OF BLOCK 011


}
```

**Update:**

From your comments:

`String retmsg = "3O|1|" + rackId + "^" + positionNumber + "^" + sampleId + "^B||" + testIds + "|" + priority + "|" + sysDate + "|||||" + orderType + "";` Where **testIds** is the list of tests to perform.

example multitest order send `4O|1||4^1^          12345678^B|^^^^WBC\^^^^RBC\^^^^HGB\^^^^HCT\^^^^MCV\^^^^MCH\^^^^MCHC\^^^^PLT\^^^^RDW-SD\^^^^RDW-CV\^^^^PDW\^^^^MPV\^^^^P-LCR\^^^^PCT\^^^^NEUT#\^^^^LYMPH#\^^^^MONO#\^^^^EO#\^^^^BASO#\^^^^NEUT%\^^^^LYMPH%\^^^^MONO%\^^^^EO%\^^^^BASO%\^^^^NRBC#\^^^^NRBC%\^^^^IG#\^^^^IG%|||||||N||||||||||||||F`

Get test codes from LIS manual or from company engineer and make pattern accordingly.

**Update 2**

```
Socket clientSocket = null;
public static char STX = '\002';
public static char ETX = '\003';
public static char ETB = '\027';
public static char EOT = '\004';
public static char ENQ = '\005';
public static char ACK = '\006';
public static char NAK = '\025';
public static char CR = '\r';
public static char LF = '\n';
public static char MOR = '>';
public static char FS = '\034';
public static char GS = '\035';
public static char RS = '\036';
public static char SFS = '\027';
public static char VT = 0x0B; //END OF BLOCK 011
public static Vector<String> vecMessages = new Vector<String>();
private static int currentMsgCount = 0;
private static ServerSocket server;
private static Socket connection;
Message mes = new Message();

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    server = new ServerSocket(12221);
    boolean stopped = false;

    System.out.println(" start... ");
    connection = server.accept();
    System.out.println("wait for connection");
    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    String currentMsg = "";
    int clientIntMessage;

//    String h1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6 = "";
//    h1 = "1H|@^\\|ODM-IdfDGIWA-36|||GeneXpert     PC^GeneXpert^4.8|||||LIS||P|1394-97|20070521100245" + ProtocolASCII.LF
//            + "P|1" + ProtocolASCII.LF
//            + "O|1|SID-818||^^^TestId-12|S|20070812140500|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q" + ProtocolASCII.LF
//            + "L|1|F" + ProtocolASCII.LF;
//    s2 = "P|1";
//    s3 = "O|1|SID-818||^^^TestId-12|S|20070812140500|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
//    //s4 = "O|2|SID-818||^^^TestId-14|S|20070812140600|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
//    //s5 = "O|3|SID-818||^^^TestId-16|S|20070812140700|||||A||||ORH||||||||||Q";
//    s6 = "L|1|F";
//
//    String retmsg = h1;
//    //logException("OrderMessae   :" + retmsg);
//    retmsg = ProtocolASCII.STX + retmsg + ProtocolASCII.CR + ProtocolASCII.ETX + ProtocolMessage.getCheckSum(retmsg) + ProtocolASCII.CR + ProtocolASCII.LF;



    clientIntMessage = inFromClient.read();
        //while (clientIntMessage != ProtocolASCII.EOT) {
        while (true) {

            while (clientIntMessage != EOT) {
                clientIntMessage = inFromClient.read();
                currentMsg += String.valueOf(Character.toChars(clientIntMessage));
                // System.out.println(currentMsg);
                if (clientIntMessage == ENQ) {
                    outToClient.writeBytes("" + ACK);
                    System.out.println("[ACK] on Analyzer [ENQ]");
                } else if (clientIntMessage == ACK) {

                    System.out.println("Analyzer [ACK]");
                    if (vecMessages.size() == currentMsgCount) {
                        vecMessages.clear();
                        currentMsgCount = 0;
                        outToClient.writeBytes("" + EOT);
                        System.out.println("Host [EOT]");
                    } else {
                        String msg = (String) vecMessages.get(currentMsgCount++);

                        outToClient.writeBytes(msg);
//                                System.out.println("Msg " + msg.substring(0, msg.length() - 4));
                    }
                } else if (clientIntMessage == LF) {
                    outToClient.writeBytes("" + ACK);
                } else if (clientIntMessage == NAK) {
                    System.out.println(" Analyzer sent [NAK] ");
                }

            }

            System.out.println(currentMsg);
            mes.parser(currentMsg);

            clientIntMessage = 0;
            currentMsg = "";

        }
//        connection.close();
//        stopped = true;
    }

    public static class Message {
//        machine Send This Query   ==>6.3.2.1.5 Example of Upload Message – Instrument System Sends Host Query
//        H|@^\|b4a88d9adab947a7b3dca2b534119c25||ICU^GeneXpert^1.0|||||LIS||P|1394-97|20070521100245 
//        Q|1|PatientID-556^SpecimenID-888||||||||||O@N 
//        L|1|N 

        public static Vector<String> vecMessages = new Vector<String>();
//        make message for machine

        public String HeaderMessage() {
            String retmsg = "H|@^\\|ccc6ade20d3623314sffa3e287f2314ad||LIS|||||ICU^GeneXpert^1.0||P|1394-97|20070521100245";
//        System.out.println("HeaderMessage  :" + retmsg);
            retmsg = STX + retmsg + CR + ETX + getCheckSum(retmsg) + CR + LF;

            return retmsg;
        }
        //  P|1       
        //      6.3.1.3.3 Patient Information Record     Find in Document and make it as per document

        public String PatientMessage(Patient pat) {  //(Patient pat)

            String retmsg = "P|1|||" + pat.getMRNO() + "|^" + pat.getPatientName() + "||" + pat.getDOB() + "|" + pat.getGender() + "|||||^Dr.SKM-LAS||||||||||||^^^EAST";

            retmsg = STX + retmsg + CR + ETX + getCheckSum(retmsg) + CR + LF;

            return retmsg;
        }
//                6.3.1.3.4 Test Order Record      Find in Document

        public String orderMessage(String sampleId, String testIds, String orderType, String rackId, String positionNumber, String priority) {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmSS");
            String sysDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());

            String retmsg = "3O|1|" + rackId + "^" + positionNumber + "^" + sampleId + "^B||" + testIds + "|" + priority + "|" + sysDate + "|||||" + orderType + "";

            retmsg = STX + retmsg + CR + ETX + getCheckSum(retmsg) + CR + LF;

            return retmsg;
        }

//        6.3.1.3.5 Message Terminator Record    Find in Document
        public String terminatorMessage(String type) {
            String retmsg = "L|1|" + type;

            retmsg = STX + retmsg + CR + ETX + getCheckSum(retmsg) + CR + LF;
            return retmsg;
        }

        public String getCheckSum(String msg) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
                sum += msg.charAt(i);
            }
            sum += 16; //adding CR and ETX AND ETB
            sum = sum % 256;
            String checksum = Integer.toHexString(sum).toUpperCase();
            if (checksum.length() == 1) {
                checksum = "0" + checksum;
            }
            //System.out.println("\n Check Sum is ="+checksum);
            return checksum;
        }

        public void parser(String input) {
//        Use StringTokenizer for split or split

            if (input.charAt(1) == 'Q' || input.charAt(2) == 'Q') {

                //Q|1|PatientID-556^SpecimenID-888||||||||||O@N 
//                        Split it and get information which machine send in Query SampleId and other
                String rackId = "get from Query to check document";
                String positionNumber = "get from Query to check document";
                String sampleId = "get from Query to check document";

//                        this.FetchOrders1(machineId, sampleId);     // for dummy Sample Run
                this.FetchOrders1("abc", sampleId);
                this.setMesType("Q");

            }

        }

        public void FetchOrders1(String machineId, String sampleId) {
            try {
                this.vecMessages.add(HeaderMessage());
                this.vecMessages.add(PatientMessage()); //Define patient information
                this.vecMessages.add(orderMessage(sampleId, "test", "N", "rackId", "positionNumber", "R"));
                this.vecMessages.add(terminatorMessage("N"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }`
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Muhammad for your answer. I'm checking it to get the best. the machine I use is the GeneXpert from http://www.cepheid.com used to do the molecular tests. I'll come back to you if I have any other questions.

Comment: Re Muhammad. I Know now about the checksum of my machine. You can find it description here https://fr.scribd.com/document/350221421/Rev-e-Genexpert-Lis-Protocol-Specification.
You said that I don’t need to send every message one by one. So do I have to create a concatenation of all parties, can you provide me one example from your four parts, because i see that `retmsg` use only one part. This will help me to see if I have to include Ascii chars. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Muhammad Nadeem Can you please help me in LIS?

Answer (score 0):

Your message should include a carriage return (CR) at the end of each string. It can be added as a String in Java in this way: "\r".

Furthermore, the byte array that you write to the outputstream should include the following in this order: STX, frame number, message string (inclusive of the CR character mentioned earlier) ETX, two uppercase checksum characters, CR, LF.

The special ASCII characters (STX, ETX etc.) are mentioned here: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)